# Google Maps API - Offset for Marker Image - Replace Marker - Not at GeoPosition

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've an image (a circle) which should indicate a specific metropolitan area. Also I've got the `GeoPosition` of all my relevant areas.

If I place my markers, the bottom-center of my image is at the marker's `GeoPosition`. But because its an aerial view I'd like to give the image an offset, so the **center** of my cirle-image is at that `GeoPosition`...

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to *LeJared* I found the solution. My problem was that I thought that `MarkerImage` replaces the `Marker`. But you have to define the image first and insert it later in the `Marker`.

**Example:**

First define the image:

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("some/path/image.png",
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
        null, 
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
        new google.maps.Point(75, 35)
    );
```

Then insert it into the regular marker:

```
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: "My Title",
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! And for those still looking for a solution, please see my answer below for the way to do it in the new API.

Answer (score 10):

Starting from Google API version 3.11, [`MarkerImage` was replaced by `Icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons). So here is the new way to scale a marker to 50px and position it so that its **center** is on the geolocation:

```
var image = {
        url: '/some/path/image.png',
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 25),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    };

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      icon: image,
      title: 'title',
      map: map
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify where the anchor point in your markerImage is. See docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#MarkerImage

If not specified google assume the center of the bottom edge of your markerImage as anchor point.

Here is an example at the API docs how to build a complex marker with correct markerImage: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex?hl=de

Comment: i read this but the `anchor` doesnt seem to work for me... Is this the correct usage within the definition of my marker? `anchor: new google.maps.Point(30,0)`

Comment: ah! I'm using the `Marker` and not the `MarkerImage`. The marker has no such property... Now I just need to figure out how to make my `MarkerImage` work :)

Comment: Well, the example above has everything you need and it is not much code, so you may figure it out easily or just adopt the code for your own project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it.

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos,
  map: map,
  icon: {
    url: src,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 25),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
  }
});
```